# How to Update Characters Inserted With CursorPosition (C/Windows API)

Tags: c, windows, api

**USING C ON CODELIGHT WITH MinGW COMPILER.**

I am trying to make a simple ASCII game. I used a 2D array to make a map and then I used a function that put my cursor on a specific point on the array to track the players movement through the keystrokes WASD(function is gotoXY(int x, int y). I was able to get it working (kind of) but I have questions regarding a couple of things that didn't come out as expected.

1. This snippet of my code occurs whenever the user presses the key a (to go left). The un-commented part prints out the character, '@', in the correct position, however it does not update the previous position that should have a '-' which represents a blank tile. That is what I used the commented code for, however, when I run the program with all of these lines un-commented it crashes whenever I press 'a'. The gotoXY() function just points the cursor toward whichever x, y coordinate it takes as arguments. Why is my code crashing when the commented parts are added?(Lines 18-22)

   ```
           //gotoXY(x, y);
           //printf('-');
           x-=2;
           gotoXY(x, y);
           printf("@");
   ```
2. Also, whenever I press the key to move my character it shoots across the screen way too fast. I tried using system("pause") to fix this, but that didn't work. So, is there a way to delay for a little while after certain keys are pressed? This way the @ character moves across the screen slower and more consistently.

**FUNCTIONS:**

```
  printBoard(char board[50][50]); //Prints the gameboard just a 50 by 50 tile
  createBoard(int size, int xPos, int yPos); //Creates the array
  gotoXY(int x, int y); //Sets position of Cursor
```

**PICTURES:**

-[Program before key is pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdZLR.jpg)

-[Program after key is pressed (lines still commented)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f612.jpg)

-[Program after key is pressed (lines un-commented)](https://imgur.com/a/X411J)

**QUESTIONS:**

1.Why does my code crash?

2.How do I slow down my character from being typed to screen so fast.

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>


void createBoard(int size, int xPos, int yPos);
void printBoard(char board[50][50]);
int main()
{
    int xPos = 32, yPos = 21, bSize = 50;
    createBoard(bSize, xPos, yPos);
    int x = 42, y = 32;                  //Starting coords for player

    while(1){
        if(GetKeyState(65)<0){  //left
            //gotoXY(x, y);
            //printf('-');
            x-=2;               //Moves 1 space left
            gotoXY(x, y);
            printf("@");
        }
        if(GetKeyState(83)<0){  //down
             y+=2;
             gotoXY(x, y);
             printf("@");
        }
        if(GetKeyState(68)<0){  //right
            x+=2;
            gotoXY(x, y);
            printf("@");
        } 
        if(GetKeyState(87)<0){  //up
             y-=2;
             gotoXY(x, y);
             printf("@");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

void printBoard(char board[50][50]){
     HANDLE  hConsole;
     hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
     int i, j;

     for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 50; j++){
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,7); //Sets tiles to white
            if(board[i][j]=='@'){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 4);  //Sets @ to red
            }
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void createBoard(int size, int xPos, int yPos){
    int i, j;
    char sampleBoard[size][size], person = '@';

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
            sampleBoard[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }

    sampleBoard[xPos][yPos] = person;
    printBoard(sampleBoard);
}

void gotoXY(int x, int y) {
        //Initialize the coordinates
        COORD coord = {x, y};
        //Set the position
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
        return;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't write the code like this

```
printf('-');
```

but you can write this code as

```
printf("-");
```

Comment: Sometimes I just can't believe my stupidity, Thank you.